Now I have an other problem, when I import a fbx it shows like this in MIxamo, without textures
This is Mixamo, the FBX has no texture.

This is the FBX imported in Mixamo. Having some issues with textures in Blender.


Having troubles with textures in Blender.

Hello, please provide images and more details of your problem. :)

You'll need to edit your original post and add screenshots and a bit more detail.

Did you pack your materials before exporting?

No, I DIDNT...I saved all the textures as images, Im just following a tutorial from YouTube and I´m a begginer. How do I do that

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

It's possible that .fbx export why there are no materials or textures applies here but without more details it's impossible to tell.
